# scrcpy won't run when the flutter app is opened in the IDE

Tags: flutter, ubuntu

hi guys so i'm using a physical device during development and i also have scrcpy screen share installed. the problem is every-time i open a flutter project in the IDE the scrcpy stops and i don't quite understand what's causing this problem.

i'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE opens another version of adb. Check the output of scrcpy (run scrcpy-console.bat on Windows).

See https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/FAQ.md#conflicts-between-adb-versions